# How to fix the position of table while increasing size of select element onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to increase the width of the select element onmouseover and decrease the width onmouseout.The select element is defined under td element of a table.I have done some coding to change its size but it is affecting table position.

How to solve this?

Please Help me out.

```
<head>
<script>

function AdjustWidth(ddl) {
var maxWidth = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < ddl.length; i++) {
    if (ddl.options[i].text.length > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = ddl.options[i].text.length;
    }
}
ddl.style.width = maxWidth * 27 + "px";

}
function AdjustWidthOut(ddl) {
var maxWidth = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < ddl.length; i++) {
    if (ddl.options[i].text.length > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = ddl.options[i].text.length;
    }
}
ddl.style.width = maxWidth * 7 + "px"; 
}
</script>
</head>
 <table>
  <tr>                            
   <td valign="top"><strong style="color: #3265a6">Area:&nbsp;</strong></td>
   <td>
     <select onmouseover="AdjustWidth(this)" onmouseout="AdjustWidthOut(this)">
         <option value="">x</option>
         <option value="">y</option>
         <option value="">z</option>
         <option value="">x</option>
     </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Why do you say it is changing table position? I only see width getting increased/decreased.

Comment: I know, probably this is only an example, btw a body tag sometime can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to do what you've instructed it to do.

During `onmouseover`, it sets the `select`'s width to 27px, because the longest `option` is one character.

During `onmouseout`, it sets the `select`'s width to 7px.

Note that 27px is not wide enough to show a single character within the `select`.  7px is barely wide enough to show the drop-down arrow.

In the snippet below, I've added divs that are 27px and 7px.  You'll see that your `select` box matches each of them during `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`.

If you want the `select` to be wider, use values larger than 27 and 7.  You may need to experiment to find what works best for you.

If you want the `select` to return to its original width during `onmouseout`, you can do so like this:

```
function AdjustWidthOut(ddl) {
  ddl.style.width = 'auto;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
function AdjustWidth(ddl) {
  var maxWidth = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < ddl.length; i++) {
    if (ddl.options[i].text.length > maxWidth) {
      maxWidth = ddl.options[i].text.length;
    }
  }
  ddl.style.width = maxWidth * 24 + "px";
}

function AdjustWidthOut(ddl) {
  var maxWidth = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < ddl.length; i++) {
    if (ddl.options[i].text.length > maxWidth) {
      maxWidth = ddl.options[i].text.length;
    }
  }
  ddl.style.width = maxWidth * 7 + "px"; 
}
```

```css
#D1 {
  width: 27px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}

#D2 {
  width: 7px;
  height: 20px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>27px:
   <td><div id="D1"></div>
  <tr>
   <td>7px:
   <td><div id="D2"></div>
  <tr>                            
   <td valign="top"><strong style="color: #3265a6">Area:&nbsp;</strong></td>
   <td>
     <select onmouseover="AdjustWidth(this)" onmouseout="AdjustWidthOut(this)">
         <option value="">x</option>
         <option value="">y</option>
         <option value="">z</option>
         <option value="">x</option>
     </select>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set a width for your table and/or your rows and columns, otherwise your table width is set to 100% of its content. Take a look at this fiddle I created which only changes the width of your dropdown element.

http://jsfiddle.net/1k03tvmu/

```
table{border: 1px solid;}
tr{border: 1px solid;}
td{ width: 100px; position: relative;}
td.content{width: 1000px; }
```